# Avoiding an always-empty regex group with re.findall

Tags: python, regex, tuples

I have a list of string lists, and am looping through each list to search for a regex pattern, which is using regex groups and produces 3 groups, so the output is in a tuple of 3, as shown below:

```
regex = '((:(?:\w+\s)+)?\w+)\[((?:\+|\-)\d)\]'


matches = []

for line in sentences:

    result = re.findall(regex, str(line))
    matches.append(result)
```

Producing the following output:

```
[[('very good', '', '+3'), ('good', '', '+2')]]
```

However, I do not want the middle group to be output in the list, as you can see, it is always empty, how do I modify the regex pattern or modify what I am using to make sure only 'very good' and '+3' (for example in the first match) appear as the tuple ('very good', '+3') and NOT the middle blank tuple?

I.e. I want my output to be:

```
[[('very good', '+3'), ('good', '+2')]]
```

Comment: You need more `?:`, then.

Comment: I note that your regex starts with `'((:(?:`. Did you mean for that to be `'((?:(?:`?

Comment: Re-write to use only as many capturing groups as you need, `(\w+(?:\s+\w+)*)\[([+-]\d)]`

Comment: Wiktor your solution was what was needed (along with the others who noted the same thing), if you post it as an answer I will select it as the solution - thanks!! Also how did you know it was more ? and not less ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to revamp the pattern to match and capture only what is necessary:

```py
(\w+(?:\s+\w+)*)\[([+-]\d)]
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mhfpHw/1).

*Details*:

- `(\w+(?:\s+\w+)*)` - Group 1: one or more word chars and then zero or more occurrences of one or more whitespaces and one or more word chars
- `\[` - a `[` char
- `([+-]\d)` - Group 2: `+` or `-` and then a digit
- `]` - a `]` char.